# How do I use an initialization list with a base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, initialization-list

Given the following:

```
struct A
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

struct B : public A
{
    int baz;
};
```

How would I construct a `B` with an initialization list that also constructs the elements in `A`? The following does not seem to work, but I am looking for something like:

```
B my_b{{1, 2}, 3}; // foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it without adding an explicit constructor and doing much of the work yourself:

```
struct B : public A
{
  B(const A &a, int _baz) : A{a}, baz{_baz} {}
  int baz;
};

B my_b{{1, 2}, 3};
```

And you'll have to keep that container in sync with `B`'s members.

If you had used containment instead of inheritance, then `B` would still be an aggregate and therefore you could use aggregate initialization.